# CCleaner is not downloading with PowerShell commands

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I tried to download CCleaner using PowerShell with this command line. All I can see is a setup file is download but it is not from CCleaner.

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner/download/standard/', (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:Downloads').Self.Path + '\CCleanerUpdated.exe')"
```

Comment: Should your comma be a semicolon? Also you definitely can remove `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`.

Comment: Remember that we can't see your screen, so we don't know what "setup file download but it is not from CCleaner" means.

Comment: There is a .exe file download in which I name I wanted to. But it is not CCleaner that I was expecting.

Comment: Why is it not what you are expecting? Any difference with a manual download?

Comment: Again: We cannot see your screen. You need to provide sufficient detail in your question about what is happening, because (to repeat) we cannot see your screen.

Comment: @bill_stewart A unknown file is downloaded with the given name. When I open it nothing happens. Please try that code and let me know.

Comment: The sensible conclusion for this case, I think, is that the code you are running is not doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

I created a Powershell script : `Download_CCleaner.ps1` that can be launched by a batch file :

***Download_CCleaner.ps1***

```
cls
$start_time = Get-Date
$Folder = "$PSScriptRoot\DownloadFolder\"
# We create a SubFolder Named "DownloadFolder" in the same path of the script if it doesn't exists yet !
If ((Test-Path -Path $Folder) -eq 0) { New-Item -Path $Folder -ItemType Directory | Out-Null }
$url = "https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup578.exe"
$output = $Folder + $url.Split("/")[-1]
Write-Host "`r`n          Please Wait a While ... Downloading CCleaner is in Progress ..."
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
$Elapsed_Time = "$((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Minutes) Minutes(M) : $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) Secondes(s)"
cls
Write-Host "`r`n          Running Script Time taken is : $Elapsed_Time"
```

---

***Download_CCleaner.bat***

```
@echo off
Title CCleaner Downloader by Hackoo 2021
cls & Mode 85,7 & color 9E
echo(
echo        Please Wait a While ... Trying to Download CCleaner ... 
Powershell -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -C "./Download_CCleaner.ps1"
Timeout /T 10 /NoBreak>nul
```