# Download and Install CCleaner using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I tried this below command line to download and install CCleaner using PowerShell. But I got errors, it was a guess try, and I would appreciate if you could modify to a working command.

```
powershell.exe -Command "$Path = $env:TEMP; $Installer = 'ccsetup578.exe'; Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner/download/standard' -OutFile $Path$Installer; Start-Process -FilePath $Path$Installer -Args '/silent /install' -Verb RunAs -Wait; Remove-Item $Path$Installer"
```

Comment: _But I got errors_.. Then show these errors. One thing I noticed is that you combine the path for download as `$Path$Installer`, which doesn't make a correct path (missing a backslash) Use [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) for that.

Comment: @theo Do you mind fixing it and see how it works on your side?

Comment: As with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66967249/1701026), you need to add more details for us to be able to help you. Start with reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specific to your case; separate a [common command quoting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Powershell.exe+quote&tab=votes) from a specific command failure by opening a PowerShell window and invoking each seperate command (and add the results of this *to the question*).

Answer (score 0):

"https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner/download/standard" - .html, not .exe

need

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup578.exe" -OutFile "$env:Temp\ccsetup578.exe"

P.S. Ccleaner - placebo

Use C:\Windows\System32\cleanmgr.exe /LOWDisk